# How to cite title and reference and page numbers with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I want to be able to cite a specific page from a reference using biblatex.
I have noticed that `from \textcite[109]{Klein:400738}` would print the author's name with the brackets containing the page number and reference's label as so: "from Klein [1, p.109]". Though, I would prefer the title to be printed instead of the author's name: "from « Basic concept I » [1, p.109]".
I kinda made a "homemade" fix to it by simply calling both `\citetitle{Klein:400738}\cite[109]{Klein:400738}` but I was wondering if there was not any default or cleaner way of doing so.

MWE if needed.

```
\documentclass[french, 11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    hyperref=true,
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Klein:400738,
    author  = {Klein, H.},
    title   = {Basic concepts I},
    journal = {{CAS - CERN Accelerator School: RF Engineering for Particle Accelerators}},
    month = {apr},
    year    = {1991},
    doi = {10.5170/CERN-1992-003.97},
    pages = {97-124}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Default citation with page number: \cite[109]{Klein:400738}\\
Textcite printing the author: \textcite[109]{Klein:400738}\\
My solution: \citetitle{Klein:400738}~\cite[109]{Klein:400738}\\
Improved one: ?
\printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this construction more often, it is a very good idea to define a dedicated citation command with `\titletextcite`.

We can steal some of the code for `\textcite` and simplify it a bit to end up with

```
\documentclass[french, 11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{titletextcite}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}%
  \printtext{\bibopenbracket}\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \multicitedelim}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\titletextcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{titletextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Klein:400738,
  author  = {Klein, H.},
  title   = {Basic concepts I},
  journal = {{CAS - CERN Accelerator School: RF Engineering for Particle Accelerators}},
  month   = apr,
  year    = {1991},
  doi     = {10.5170/CERN-1992-003.97},
  pages   = {97-124}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Default citation with page number: \cite[109]{Klein:400738}

Textcite printing the author: \textcite[109]{Klein:400738}

My solution: \citetitle{Klein:400738}~\cite[109]{Klein:400738}

Improved one: \titletextcite[109]{Klein:400738}

\printbibliography[title={Bibliographie}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Improved one: “Basic concepts I” [1, p. 109]]